# ALSA Audio Capture block on Simulink

Tags: simulink, alsa

I need to read and work into a matlab code block with the data coming from the "Raspberry Pi ALSA Audio Capture block" inside Simulink frame. I'm using Matlab r2013a and matlab r2013b, with raspberry Pi Simulink libraries.

That's because i need to develope a special audio analysis.

So my question is: How can I read the stream of data coming from the "Raspberry Pi Audio Capture" block, and modify them before to "plot" or "record" the modified data into a file?

And how to plot such a kind of data in a streaming plot?

And how to record such a kind of data into a file?

Thank you!

Comment: Remembering that ALSA audio capture block is a part of RaspberryPi toolbox, we can see that the Scope blocks doesn't work on RaspberryPi and "To Multimedia File" also doesn't work on Raspberry.
This commands ONLY works on the host PC that is NOT CONNECTED in the FINAL WORK so :-(

This script SOMETIMES works:

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
fileID = fopen('/home/pi/Desktop/THENAMEOFTHEFILE.txt','a');
    
fprintf(fileID,'%12.8f\n',INCOMINGDATAVARIABLENAME);


if stopIN == 1

fclose(fileID);

end
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

Answer (score 0):

Do you have DSP System toolbox? Start by looking at the audio Example in that toolbox. There are many of them. For plotting you need scope blocks. You can find them under "Sinks" in Simulink library. For writing you need "To Multimedia File" block which is also in DSP System toolbox.